# Call a sproc from another sproc on a different machine

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL server 2000.
I have a stored procedure sitting on machine A.  I want to call this stored procedure from within a stored procedure on machine B.  How do I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Linked Server feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778.aspx) of SQL Server.

> A linked server configuration allows
>   Microsoft SQL Server to execute
>   commands against OLE DB data sources
>   on different servers. Linked servers
>   offer these advantages:
>
> - Remote server access
> - The ability to issue distributed
>     queries, updates, commands, and
>     transactions on heterogeneous data
>     sources across the enterprise.
> - The ability to address diverse data sources similarly.

A call could look like this:

```
  exec MyRemoteServer.MyDB.dbo.sp_MyStoredProc
```

Answer (score 2):

Read this [blog post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/06/sql-server-executing-remote-stored-procedure-calling-stored-procedure-on-linked-server/).  Essentially, if the server is already set up as a linked server you can use EXEC RemoteServer.DatabaseName.DatabaseOwner.StoredProcedureName